# Writing file to unix directory using spark cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark application which runs in local mode currently and writes an output to a file in a local UNIX directory.

Now, I want to run the same job in yarn cluster mode and still want to write into that UNIX folder.

Can I use the same saveAsTextFile(path)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But it is not the best practice to do that. The spark itself can run standalone and on distributed file system. The reason we are using distributed file system is that the data is huge and the expected output might be huge.

So, if you are compeltely sure that the output will fit in to your local file system, go for it or you can save it to your local storage using the below command.

```
bin/hadoop fs -copyToLocal /hdfs/source/path /localfs/destination/path
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak. I assume this is a hadoop command to copy the file from hdfs to local directory. But, how can I write to the file in UNIX directory from with a spark application/program.

Comment: Yes, it is. What do you mean by write to the file? Are you asking like real writing to a file like read, append and write?

Comment: Yes, in my case, I want to Append to a file from with a spark application.

Comment: Whatever operation you perform on spark, it has to work on RDD. So, it needs to load the file into RDD and then perform the operation you require, in your case look at how parallelize works. It performs a transformation and then you save the RDD using the saveAsTextFile(path).